Having trouble determining if my data is normally distributed or not using QQ-plot in R
I'm having trouble interpreting my QQ-plot from the data attached. Shapiro-Wilk test p-value = 0.14 which I know means the distribution does not meaningfully stray from a normal one. Can anyone confirm if the QQ plot generated from this data supports this conclusion or I should be more cautious? Code is attached for anyone to copy and paste.
Note: I made this in R/RStudio
PHD<- c(3.3,
    3.3,
    3.2,
    3.3,
    3.5,
    3.1,
    3.3,
    2.8,
    3.5,
    2.5,
    3.5,
    3.2,
    2.9,
    3.2,
    2.3,
    3.3,
    3.6,
    3.1,
    2.8,
    3.8,
    3.1,
    3.1,
    3.0,
    3.4,
    3.0,
    3.0,
    3.2,
    3.6,
    3.1,
    3.9,
    3.6,
    3.4,
    3.7,
    3.7,
    3.3,
    3.7,
    3.3,
    3.1,
    3.4,
    2.8,
    3.6,
    3.4,
    3.6,
    3.2,
    3.7,
    3.4,
    3.3,
    4.1,
    3.5,
    3.6,
    3.3,
    3.4,
    3.3,
    3.3,
    3.7,
    3.1,
    3.4,
    3.8,
    3.1,
    3.9,
    3.3,
    3.6,
    3.2,
    4.0,
    3.6,
    3.3,
    3.3,
    3.5,
    3.3,
    3.8,
    4.1,
    3.7,
    3.7,
    4.0,
    3.8,
    4.0,
    3.4,
    4.1,
    4.0,
    3.6,
    3.9,
    3.5,
    3.2,
    2.7,
    3.2,
    3.3,
    3.7,
    2.9)

library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(PHD)

ggplot(data = data, aes(sample = PHD))+
  geom_qq()+
  geom_qq_line(size = 1, color = "red")


Of course, no empirical distribution is exactly normal, but yours seems close because your data points fall close to the qq line. On the left side, the points are a bit below and on the right a bit above, so your distribution is bit "heavy tailed" ... more points than expected at the extremes. Since your data is rounded to 0.1, one way to explore the question is to generate normally distributed random samples, round them, and see the results. For me, it looks similar to your empirical data.
test_data <- round(rnorm(500, mean=mean(PHD), sd = sd(PHD)),1)
df = data.frame(test_data)
ggplot(data = df, aes(sample=test_data))+
  geom_qq()+
  geom_qq_line(size = 1, color = "red")

On the other hand, formal tests say close, but not quite
shapiro.test(data$PHD)

